# Movable Type: Converting to json file

Tags: json, movabletype

I am trying to convert some data to json format using Movable Types template tags and so far I have below code. This code is coming up with blank results. I am not very knowledgeable with this template code so any help would be appreciated.

```
<mt:SetVar name="entries" function="undef">
<mt:Tags>
    <$mt:TagName trim_to="1" upper_case="1" setvar="current_index"$>

    <mt:SetVar name="e" function="undef">
    <mt:SetHashVar name="e">
        <mt:if name="current_index" ne="$last_index"><mt:getvar name="current_index"></mt:if>
        <mt:TagName setvar="name">
        <mt:setvarblock name="url">https://www.foo.com/tags/<$mt:TagName encode_url="1"$></mt:setvarblock>
    </mt:SetHashVar>
    <$mt:var name="current_index" setvar="last_index"$>
    <mt:SetVar name="entries" key="$last_index" value="$e">
</mt:Tags>
<mt:Var name="entries" to_json="1">
```

Here is what I am expecting

```
{
  "A": [
    {
      "name": "Abrand",
      "url": "#"
    },
    {
      "name": "Abrand",
      "url": "#"
    },
    {
      "name": "Abrand",
      "url": "#"
    }
  ],
  "B": [
    {
      "name": "Bbrand",
      "url": "#"
    },
    {
      "name": "Bbrand",
      "url": "#"
    }
  ],
  "C": [
    {
      "name": "Cbrand",
      "url": "#"
    {
      "name": "Cbrand",
      "url": "#"
    },
    {
      "name": "Cbrand",
      "url": "#"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Your two occurrences of `<mt:SetVar name="whatever" function="undef">` won't produce anything (the functions are strictly limited to what's listed in the docs at https://movabletype.org/documentation/appendices/tags/var.html#function and "undef" isn't a function, plus the way this tag is used it would output something, not set a variable).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<mt:Tags sort_by="name" sort_order="ascend" limit="1">
    <$mt:TagName trim_to="1" upper_case="1" setvar="current_index"$>
    <$mt:SetVar name="last_index" value="$current_index"$>
</mt:Tags>

<mt:Tags sort_by="name" sort_order="ascend">
    <$mt:TagName trim_to="1" upper_case="1" setvar="current_index"$>
    <mt:SetHashVar name="e">
        <mt:TagName setvar="name">
        <mt:SetVarBlock name="url">https://www.foo.com/tags/<$mt:TagName encode_url="1"$></mt:SetVarBlock>
    </mt:SetHashVar>

    <mt:if name="current_index" eq="$last_index">
        <$mt:SetVar name="hold" function="push" value="$e"$>
    <mt:else>
        <$mt:Var name="entries{$last_index}" value="$hold"$>
        <$mt:SetVar name="last_index" value="$current_index"$>
        <$mt:SetVar name="hold" value=""$>
        <$mt:SetVar name="hold" function="push" value="$e"$>
    </mt:if>
</mt:Tags>

<mt:Var name="entries" to_json="1">
```

(I tested it on MT 6.2.2, but should work on 5.x)

Comment: some how the tags are sort_by name it dose not export alphabetically. Is this same with your case?

Comment: I didn't check that, but I've seen strange sorting behavior with tags before (specifically I have a MT site that does not sort French diacritics properly, it might have to do with Perl or MySQL in addition to MT, all of them are involved in the sorting). Reading the doc at https://movabletype.org/documentation/appendices/tags/tags.html I'm afraid name is the only usable column for sorting. If the structure remains coherent, I'm guessing you are consuming the resulting JSON file and sorting would not be an issue, would it?

Comment: ok I see so there are some issues. I guess I have to sort them with js. Thanks for the tip!